# How to use custom HTTP methods in Symfony2 FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, http, symfony, fosrestbundle

I use FOSRestBundle for my RESTful API. Lets say I want to use some custom HTTP method for WebDav or something else. Lets say I want to implement imaginary FIRE method. How can I implement it in this bundle?

I'd like to have **fireResourceAction()** in my controller and set up symfony so I could call this method like this:

```
curl -i -X FIRE http://my.api.address/resource.
```

I know it is unusual and bad practice to use method outside of HTTP defined ones but still... I can implement it in pure PHP. I can call such methods in JavaScript. How to do it in Symfony?

Comment: You should not create custom HTTP verbs. Use the available ones from the RFC.

Comment: I know that, but theoreticly it is possible to use custom verbs, ex. WebDAV has some extra ones. So how can I use them in FOSRestBundle?

Comment: WebDAV uses verbs, which are defined in the RFCs.